How do I compare new IDs with a column of existing IDs and allowcate a timestamp if two IDs match on Google Sheets?
I would really appreciate it if someone could help me get this tricky function right on google sheets.
Everytime stock is scanned I would like to see the timestamp next to that stock ID on google sheets. I am using an ESP32 to send scanned IDs (RFIDs) to google sheets. On my google sheets spreadsheet I already have all the existing stock IDs in a column. When the scanned IDs are sent to my spreadsheet I would like to compare those scanned IDs with the ones on my stock list and alocate a timestamp next to the stock ID if it was scanned in that time period.
Here is an example of what I would like to achieve. If one of the IDs in column B matches the ID in column A then display the current timestamp else do nothing. (Please see the attached images)
5 IDs scanned and sent to spreadsheet at 24/9/11 16:00

4 IDs scanned and sent to spreadsheet at 24/9/11 17:00

I managed to get this right with app script and a for loop but I had to use "new data" as a trigger to initiate the function when new IDs came in. I think that caused a nasty loop and was taking about 5 seconds to return a value for each cell of row C.
I also came close to getting this right with google sheets itself by comparing cell A2 with each cell of row B, =IF(OR(A2=B2,A2=B3,A2=B4,A2=B5),"timestamp").
Unfortunately,

I have to edit this function for each line which can be quite tedious and risky if there are 400 IDs.
It overides the previous timestamp with FALSE if there was no match.
I also havent figured out how to store the current time as a timestamp on GS.

I would like to be able to do this on google sheets alone if that is possible.

@doubleunary. The onEdit() function works when I personaly change the state of the trigger cells however when I change the state of the cells using google api via service account it does not trigger the onEdit() function. Is there a way around that? or is this a topic for another discussion?

The onEdit(e) simple trigger only fires when a cell is manually edited. Edits that are done by script are explicitly excluded by specification. Please ask only one question per post. Post a new question instead.

You can do that by adding two columns:
Column D holds timestamps that show when a value in column B was entered. This column is filled in by a script such as my yetAnotherTimestamp_ script.
Column E looks up timestamps in D by matching keys in A to keys in B with this formula in cell E1:
=arrayformula(ifna(vlookup(A1:A, B1:D, columns(B1:D), false)))


Thank you so much. I could never figure this out so I was doing all the comparing on the ESP32 and sending the 4byte epoch value of each ID to GS EVERY time. It worked great but now I can take out about  200 lines of code off of the ESP and I only have to send a 2 byte ID every time instead. Thank you.

is there a way that the arrayformula (at column 'E') that you gave can be bypassed of do nothing if Column 'B' whent from having a value (say 5) to not having a value (blank). What I would like is for the Timestamp at Column 'E' to not disapear but only overite.

That is a different question that will require a different solution. Please ask only one question per post. Post a new question instead.

Compare new IDs with a column of existing IDs and allowcate a timestamp if two IDs match

I tried using appscript and checked this if it's correct based on the problem given. I use the onEdit() function to trigger the scanned column only and use ternary for condition statements.
This is the output of the the code:


Code:
function onEdit(e) {
  const sheets = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('--SheetName--');
  const sheetArray = sheets.getRange(2, 1, sheets.getLastRow() - 1).getValues()
  e.range.getColumn() == 2 ? sheetArray.flat().includes(e.range.getValue()) ? sheets.getRange(e.range.getRow(), 3).setValue(new Date().toLocaleString("en-US")) : null : null;
}

Reference:

includes
ternary
onEdit


If you have questions regarding this answer, feel free to ask and comment.

Awesome! I'm sure this will work too. I will give it a try in the morning. Thank you for all the effor you put into your reply.

If this answers your question, please click the accept button on the left (check icon) and upvoting the answer.  By doing so, other people in the community, who may have the same concern as you, will know that theirs can be resolved.  If the accept button is unavailable to you, feel free to tell me. how to accept the answer
